# Stored procedure with input parameters - novel set-based approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I found an adaptation of the following script online:

```
CREATE TABLE alphaCodes
(personID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 codes CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 );

INSERT INTO alphaCodes
VALUES (1, '12300'), (1, '23400'), (1, '45623'), 
       (2, '99900'), (2, '23411'), (2, '78900'), 
       (3, '12300'), (3, '23400'), (3, '45699');
go
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPeopleWithCodes 
(@d1 CHAR(10) = NULL, @d2 CHAR(10) = NULL, 
 @d3 CHAR(10) = NULL, @d4 CHAR(10) = NULL, 
 @d5 CHAR(10) = NULL)
AS BEGIN
--cte for the alphaCodes table
WITH Patient_Diagnosis (personID, codes)
AS (SELECT personID, codes FROM alphaCodes),

codeList (codePattern)
AS
--row constructor makes a table of the variables that will be passed into the stored procedure
(SELECT X.codePattern 
  FROM (VALUES (@d1), (@d2), (@d3), (@d4), (@d5))
        AS X(codePattern)
 WHERE X.codePattern IS NOT NULL)

SELECT DISTINCT personID 
 FROM Patient_Diagnosis AS PD1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT *
          FROM codeList
         WHERE NOT EXISTS 
              (SELECT *
                 FROM Patient_Diagnosis AS PD2
                WHERE PD1.personID = PD2.personID
                  AND PD2.codes LIKE codeList.codePattern));
END; 
--for whatever reason, the % wildcard does not and and the _ has to be used
exec dbo.GetPeopleWithCodes '123___'
```

This stored procedure will take up to five input parameters and will essentially return an inner join of however many parameters you include. So if you run

```
exec dbo.getpeoplewithcodes '234___'
```

`1,2,3` will be returned.  If you run

```
exec dbo.getpeoplewithCodes '234____','123___'
```

will return `1,3`.  When I had tried to do this I used dynamic SQL to make a table with various joins to the `alphaCodes` table.  The above method is tons faster but there's one problem:  I cannot for the life of me completely understand it.  I like the `like` operator in the last join, but I don't get the first `where not exists` subquery.  Can anyone help explain what's going on?  How can you only have two references the alphaCodes table and have this thing still work?

Comment: Not exists seems to be very similar to the `IN` and `NOT IN` clauses.  Not sure what version of SQL Server you are using, but here is the MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I haven't read your code in detail, but a nested `NOT EXISTS` immediately reminds me of Celko's aircraft and pilots [example](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) to illustrate relational division. I've used this construction myself in code but always with an explanatory comment because double negatives are confusing in any context.

Comment: @Pondlife: I agree, it is confusing, and since there's the two correlated queries you can't run bits and pieces of it to break it down and have it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood it correctly, this code is intended to return a list of all the patients who have diagnosis codes matching all the input parameter patterns.

The final `SELECT` statement is a double negative stating the same requirement - it returns a distinct list of all the `Patient_Diagnosis.Patient_Id` values from rows which aren't in the set of `Patient_Diagnosis` rows which don't have codes which match the list of input parameters. This is a confusing way to write this query.

The following isn't heavily tested but appears to return the same results with only one scan of the `alphaCodes` table. I've removed the CTE on `alphaCodes` since it was redundant:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPeopleWithCodes 
(@d1 CHAR(10) = NULL, @d2 CHAR(10) = NULL, 
 @d3 CHAR(10) = NULL, @d4 CHAR(10) = NULL, 
 @d5 CHAR(10) = NULL)
AS BEGIN
WITH codeList (codePattern)
AS
(SELECT X.codePattern 
  FROM (VALUES (@d1), (@d2), (@d3), (@d4), (@d5))
        AS X(codePattern)
 WHERE X.codePattern IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT pd.PersonId 
FROM codeList cl
JOIN alphaCodes pd
ON pd.codes LIKE cl.codePattern
GROUP BY pd.personID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM codeList)
END
GO
```

Comment: google find an almost identical answer to this in a celko book.  dude must be the jam.